# Change contents within {}

Tags: auctex

I am using 
Auctex.
I found several useful shortcuts starting with `C-c`. But I could not find the keyboard shortcut to change content within {} if the cursor is within.

So, I am editing (| indicaties cursor position)

> \section{Some S|ection Name}

And I want to change this to

> \section{Completely different}

How do I do this quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the package [`expand-region`](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el).

I assume you use the proposed setup:

```el
(require 'expand-region)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-=") 'er/expand-region)
```

In that case you would select the full header `Some Section Name` with two keystrokes of <kbd>C-=</kbd>.
Then strike <kbd>C-w</kbd> to clear the header and start typing your new title.

Note, that you can install `expand-region` with `package-install` if you have properly configured [`package`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Packages.html).

Comment: I initially missed vim for the ease of doing ci{ but now I dont. Because expand-region is a much powerful tool.